# How to make video from high resolution jpg?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, jpeg

I try to make video from 2 jpeg (6912x3456 px, files is large it is 360 panoramas) with ffmpeg by

```
ffmpeg -r 1/4 -pattern_type glob -i "my_dir/*.jpg" -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 18 -vf "fps=30,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

And get for long time (maximum I waited 30 min) this output

```
ffmpeg version N-55618-ga0acc44106-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 63.100 / 56. 63.100
  libavcodec     58.115.102 / 58.115.102
  libavformat    58. 65.101 / 58. 65.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 95.100 /  7. 95.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, image2, from 'my_dir/*.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 7680x3840, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x6c1dbc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x67c3000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x67c3000] profile High, level 6.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x67c3000] 264 - core 161 r3033 0d754ec - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'my_dir/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 7680x3840, q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.115.102 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
```

Htop showes
[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb0lU.jpg)

Hardware:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 55
Model name:            Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  J1900  @ 1.99GHz
Stepping:              8
CPU MHz:               1332.718
CPU max MHz:           2415.7000
CPU min MHz:           1332.8000


MemTotal:        3749836 kB
SwapTotal:       4008956 kB
```

If I use smaller jpg (FHD or 4k resolution), ffmpeg work fine.
Is it true that PC have no enough memory for this job? There is only 8 sec video. Is there way to make this work by this PC? What are the requirements for the pc?